# Cannot complete card collection contracts

Tags: gwent

There are several collection contracts that are not marked as completed and not giving me any reward despite me having all necessary cards. For example Strange Stew and Pitch Perfect show Whispess and Temerian Drummer cards as missing.

[image]

While I actually have these cards:

[image]
[image]

I've tried tracking/untracking contracts, restarting the game.

How can I complete these contracts? I'm playing on PS4 if it matters.

Comment: If you can spare the resources, try crafting the premium/non-premium version (whichever one you don't actually have already) of the "missing" card. I had the same issue with several cards on PC and had to craft some cards again for them to count. This always worked for me, but no guarantees. Unfortunately, the contracts and achievements for Gwent are a bit buggy. Maybe they fixed some by now, but both on PC and PS4 I had several achievements not registering.